# Spring Cloud Config keeps checking out master branch

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-config

I am running into an issue with Spring Cloud Config. I have a remote git repo with my config files, which is cloned down locally for local testing.

My project has 4 bootstrap.yml files as shown below

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ConfigurationService
  profiles:
    active: dev, local
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: true
      server:
        git:
          clone-on-start: true
          search-paths: '{application}'
          username: USERNAME
          password: PASSWORD
        bootstrap: true
      enabled: true
```

**bootstrap-dev.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ConfigurationService
  profiles:
    active: dev, local
  cloud:
    config:
      label: develop

server:
  port: 0
```

**bootstrap-local.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:///${user.home}/Projects/project
          clone-on-start: false
```

**bootstrap-remote.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://bitbucket.org/
          clone-on-start: true
```

The remote repo has a master branch and a develop branch. When I checkout develop locally and start my config service it checks out the master branch.

Why is this happening and how do i stop it? I am starting the config service in the dev profile and the local profile which uses the 'develop' label as seen in bootstrap-dev.yml.